# Issues with openpgp golang gpg library

Tags: encryption, go, public-key-encryption, gnupg, openpgp

So I'm pretty new to golang and i'm struggling to get a working example going of encrypting some text with openpgp and decrypting it again.

Here is what I have so far: (https://gist.github.com/93750a142d3de4e8fdd2.git)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "bytes"
    "code.google.com/p/go.crypto/openpgp"
    "encoding/base64"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

// create gpg keys with
// $ gpg --gen-key
// ensure you correct paths and passphrase

const mysecretstring = "this is so very secret!"
const secretKeyring = "/Users/stuart-warren/.gnupg/secring.gpg"
const publicKeyring = "/Users/stuart-warren/.gnupg/pubring.gpg"
const passphrase = "1234"

func main() {
    log.Printf("Secret: ", mysecretstring)
    log.Printf("Secret Keyring: ", secretKeyring)
    log.Printf("Public Keyring: ", publicKeyring)
    log.Printf("Passphrase: ", passphrase)

    // Read in public key
    keyringFileBuffer, _ := os.Open(publicKeyring)
    defer keyringFileBuffer.Close()
    entitylist, _ := openpgp.ReadKeyRing(keyringFileBuffer)

    // encrypt string
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w, _ := openpgp.Encrypt(buf, entitylist, nil, nil, nil)
    w.Write([]byte(mysecretstring))

    // Encode to base64
    bytesp, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    encstr := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytesp)

    // Output encrypted/encoded string
    log.Printf("Encrypted Secret: ", encstr)

    // Here is where I would transfer the encrypted string to someone else 
    // but we'll just decrypt it in the same code

    // init some vars
    var entity2 *openpgp.Entity
    var entitylist2 openpgp.EntityList

    // Open the private key file
    keyringFileBuffer2, _ := os.Open(secretKeyring)
    defer keyringFileBuffer2.Close()
    entitylist2, _ = openpgp.ReadKeyRing(keyringFileBuffer2)
    entity2 = entitylist2[0]

    // Get the passphrase and read the private key.
    // Have not touched the encrypted string yet
    passphrasebyte := []byte(passphrase)
    log.Printf("Decrypting private key using passphrase")
    entity2.PrivateKey.Decrypt(passphrasebyte)
    for _, subkey := range entity2.Subkeys {
            subkey.PrivateKey.Decrypt(passphrasebyte)
    }
    log.Printf("Finished decrypting private key using passphrase")

    // Decode the base64 string
    dec, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encstr)

    // Decrypt it with the contents of the private key
    md, _ := openpgp.ReadMessage(bytes.NewBuffer(dec), entitylist2, nil, nil)
    bytess, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(md.UnverifiedBody)
    decstr := string(bytess)

    // should be done
    log.Printf("Decrypted Secret: ", decstr)

}
```

This is based off of https://github.com/jyap808/jaeger

When I run it, it seems to partially work, but only outputs some of the characters of the original string... Changing the original string causes some very weird issues.

```
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Secret: %!(EXTRA string=this is so very secret!)
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Secret Keyring: %!(EXTRA string=/Users/stuart-warren/.gnupg/secring.gpg)
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Public Keyring: %!(EXTRA string=/Users/stuart-warren/.gnupg/pubring.gpg)
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Passphrase: %!(EXTRA string=1234)
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Encrypted Secret: %!(EXTRA string=wcBMA5a76vUxixWPAQgAOkrt/LQ3u++VbJ/20egxCUzMqcMYtq+JXL7SqbB5S1KrgHhGd8RHUmxy2h45hOLcAt+kfvSz0EJ/EsCmwnbP6HRPEqiMLt6XaVS26Rr9HQHPpRBZkqnwAP0EmlYNnF5zjnU5xTcEOyyr7EYhEgDv0Ro1FQkaCL2xdBhDCXs4EdQsjVrcECWOt0KgbCWs+N/0cEdeyHwodkaDgJ7NMq/pPuviaRu4JHCIxMiyz8yhOCHOM+bI80KsJesjGrgbjnGDfJUZNYDBNc8PqzfC39lB2MBrn/w07thJxvjbep39R0u2C4eEcroTRLB+t9i4fJNiVpoSclYRSZXm5OsYYv/XwtLgAeRZ07lFEsGoHSbqGLUnHFFw4Svk4FPgCuGVpOCS4vYiisDg+ORYj8dpu/Z3gSlVJ6mhSr7H4J3i9vItRuBx4WUB4HHgmQ==)
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Decrypting private key using passphrase
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Finished decrypting private key using passphrase
2014/09/07 22:59:38 Decrypted Secret: %!(EXTRA string=this)
```

Clearly there is something I'm not understanding, so would appreciate any assistance given.

Comment: I notice Encrypt returns a WriteCloser and you never Close()d it. For some other things like `compress/gzip`, I know that can result in not all the output getting flushed. (Also best practice to check the `err`s from everything, even things that seem like they could not error.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A reminder that **security is unusually treacherous territory**, and if there's a way to call on other well-tested code even more of your toplevel task than just what Go's OpenPGP package is handling for you, consider it. It's good that at least low-level details are outsourced to `openpgp` because they're nasty and so so easy to get wrong. But tiny mistakes at any level can make crypto features worse than useless; if there's a way to write less security-critical code, that's one of the best things anyone can do for security.

On the specific question: you have to `Close()` the writer to get everything flushed out (a trait OpenPGP's writer shares with, say, `compress/gzip`'s).

Unrelated changes: the way you're printing things is a better fit `log.Println`, which just lets you pass a bunch of values you want printed with spaces in between (like, say, Python `print`), rather than needing format specifiers like `"%s"` or `"%d"`. (The "EXTRA" in your initial output is what Go's `Printf` emits when you pass more things than you had format specifiers for.) It's also best practice to check errors (I dropped `if err != nil`s where I saw a need, but inelegantly and without much thought, and I may not have gotten all the calls) and to run `go fmt` on your code.

Again, **I can't testify to the seaworthiness of this code or anything like that.** But now it round-trips all the text. I wound up with:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "code.google.com/p/go.crypto/openpgp"
    "encoding/base64"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

// create gpg keys with
// $ gpg --gen-key
// ensure you correct paths and passphrase

const mysecretstring = "this is so very secret!"
const prefix, passphrase = "/Users/stuart-warren/", "1234"
const secretKeyring = prefix + ".gnupg/secring.gpg"
const publicKeyring = prefix + ".gnupg/pubring.gpg"

func encTest() error {
    log.Println("Secret:", mysecretstring)
    log.Println("Secret Keyring:", secretKeyring)
    log.Println("Public Keyring:", publicKeyring)
    log.Println("Passphrase:", passphrase)

    // Read in public key
    keyringFileBuffer, _ := os.Open(publicKeyring)
    defer keyringFileBuffer.Close()
    entitylist, err := openpgp.ReadKeyRing(keyringFileBuffer)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // encrypt string
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w, err := openpgp.Encrypt(buf, entitylist, nil, nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = w.Write([]byte(mysecretstring))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Encode to base64
    bytesp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    encstr := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(bytesp)

    // Output encrypted/encoded string
    log.Println("Encrypted Secret:", encstr)

    // Here is where I would transfer the encrypted string to someone else
    // but we'll just decrypt it in the same code

    // init some vars
    var entity2 *openpgp.Entity
    var entitylist2 openpgp.EntityList

    // Open the private key file
    keyringFileBuffer2, err := os.Open(secretKeyring)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer keyringFileBuffer2.Close()
    entitylist2, err = openpgp.ReadKeyRing(keyringFileBuffer2)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    entity2 = entitylist2[0]

    // Get the passphrase and read the private key.
    // Have not touched the encrypted string yet
    passphrasebyte := []byte(passphrase)
    log.Println("Decrypting private key using passphrase")
    entity2.PrivateKey.Decrypt(passphrasebyte)
    for _, subkey := range entity2.Subkeys {
        subkey.PrivateKey.Decrypt(passphrasebyte)
    }
    log.Println("Finished decrypting private key using passphrase")

    // Decode the base64 string
    dec, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encstr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Decrypt it with the contents of the private key
    md, err := openpgp.ReadMessage(bytes.NewBuffer(dec), entitylist2, nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    bytess, err := ioutil.ReadAll(md.UnverifiedBody)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    decstr := string(bytess)

    // should be done
    log.Println("Decrypted Secret:", decstr)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := encTest()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, you legend. That's been bugging me for days!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your code, but the only thing i can think off, is that the order of execution is wrong. You first make a string, then you make it Base64, then you encrypt it. Now you undo the Base64 and afterwards you decrypt the encoded string. These last two must be swapped.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion sounded a plausible mistake.

Comment: [stupid comment editing limits] However: line 32 encrypt string into bytes, line 35 encode bytes into base64, line 55 decode base64 into bytes, line 56 decrypt bytes and convert back into string. You are saying that is the wrong order?

Comment: After you have encrypted your string, you decode it from base64. It is this line: dec, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encstr)
Also, in your example, using base64 is not needed. If you use 0-9 and a-Z and space ofcourse, base64 is not needed. Maybe that makes it more easier for you to test. Then later on, you can use base64 to capture everything.

Comment: I've tried removing base64 from the equation by sending the encrypted byte array straght to the decryption part with no change. I don't believe the issue is there. I've added more comments to the code and a bounty.